# In Snowflake, is there a windows SQL function to calculate cumulative values, for each group?

Tags: sql

[image: Sample Data]

Here's my sample data. I am looking to get the cumulative number of minutes per coordinates for each motorcycle, in a new column. The desired output would look like this:

[image: Desired Output]

I don't think you can partition over both motorcycle AND coordinates but intuitively, that feels like that's what I'd need to do?  Or, do I need to concatenate them both first.

And sorry, on the sql server, the 3rd column is just called 'minutes'

Comment: Hi, the title of your question mentions Snowflake, the text of your question mentions SQL Server and you’ve tagged it with snowflake-schema, which is a data modelling pattern. Please  tag your question with the actual DBMS you are using. Why don’t you think you can partition by multiple columns - what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Hi. sorry for the late reply. Was overseas for the holidays. The tagging with a mistake- which I'll change now. Yes, it does work now- when I add a coma inbetween.